# Excel VBA - Show values in loop during code run

Tags: excel, vba, loops, progress

My VBA prog shuttles through a list of 200 users in a *for next* loop as it progresses. Is there a way for a message to appear on the screen to show which user is being processed? I know this can be done using something like - msgbox "User: " mUser - but that requires "ok" to be clicked to carry on with the code.

I'm not looking for the progress bar people often ask about.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Andrew

Comment: Create a UserForm with `Label` field. Update that field everytime a new user is picked-up. close the form once complete. Please provide what you have tried for a more comprehensive response

Comment: Look at `Application.StatusBar`. You can update it each loop. Set it to `False` when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Some code I use to do what Zac describes is:

Assuming:

- The user form is called UserForm
- The user form label where the name to be shown is called Label1
- Screenupdating is off
- mUser is the info you want to show

1. Before your loop make the form visible

`UserForm.Show vbModeless`

2. In your loop (near the start)

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
UserForm.Label1.Caption = mUser
DoEvents
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

3. After your loop

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
UserForm.Label1.Caption = "Finished - Close this box"
```

Comment: Thanks all. I'll give those a go. Andrew